# How to convert a string to dictionary in c# [after applying pre-processing]

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string like this:

```
var strings1 = @"a={b},c={d},e={f},g={h},
                    i={j},k={l},m={n},o={p},q={r},s={t},u={v},w={x},
                    y={z}, alpha={beta}";
```

What am I trying to achieve is this:

1. Comma separate values
2. After separating them, trim down `'{'` and `'}'` chars from start and end.
3. Store them in a dictionary.

Output should be like this:

```
a,b
c,d
e,f    //etc..,
```

Have written this program below and it works **perfectly fine**.

**The question is, Are there any short / perfect way of doing this ?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var strings1 = @"a={b},c={d},e={f},g={h},
                i={j},k={l},m={n},o={p},q={r},s={t},u={v},w={x},
                y={z}, alpha={beta}";


            var splitString  = strings1.Split(',');
            var splitList = splitString.ToList();

            var output = new List<string>();
            splitList.ForEach(x =>
            {
               output.Add(x.Trim());
            });

            splitList = new List<string>();
            output.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    splitList.Add(x.Trim());
                });

            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            splitList.ForEach(x =>
            {
                var outpt = x.Split('=');
                dict.Add(outpt[0], outpt[1]);
            });

            var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var x in dict.Keys)
            {
                var val = dict[x];
                var y = val.TrimStart('{').ToString().TrimEnd('}').ToString();
                dict1.Add(x, y);
            }


            foreach(var y in dict1.Keys)
            {
                var stringFormatted = y + dict1[y];
                Console.Write(stringFormatted);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Updated. Quick eye. Thanks :)

Comment: Are `{`, `}` or space ever valid values, eg: `brackets={{foo}` (resulting in `"brackets","{foo"`) or `spaces={  lots of spaces   }` (resulting in `"spaces","  lots of spaces   "`)? Can the input string ever contain newlines? You show one item with a space after the comma, are there other variations of input?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @gregmac: No, the input string doesn't change much. It is pretty much the same format :)

Comment: @TnTinMn It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely.  The following Linq code should give the same results.

```
var dictionary = yourString.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim('}','{',' '));
```

Note that like your code there is no error checking for entries that are missing the equal sign.

Comment: Guys like you are legend :) I wrote the code for some 15 mins, but you complete hardly in 1 min... I think I should explore more on linq :)

Comment: @Steve That would trim all the curly braces, but based on the OP's comments that's not a concern.  Additionally their `TrimStart('{')` woudl get rid of all the "{" at the beginning.  So yeah, not an exact match for unexpected input.  Changing it to `Trim().TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}')` would make it match, but that seemed a bit much.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Without LINQ, it would look like:

```
var strings1 = @"a={b},c={d},e={f},g={h},
    i={j},k={l},m={n},o={p},q={r},s={t},u={v},w={x},
    y={z}, alpha={beta}";

var splitString  = strings1.Split(',');
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string s in splitString)
{
    var splitPair = s.Split('=');

    dict[splitPair[0].Trim()] = splitPair[1].Trim(' ', '{', '}');
}
```

Comment: What if, what if :) This answer assumes very predictable input. Error checking/handling is additional work.

Comment: Also, what if there are duplicate keys? What if keys or values contain ',' or '=' characters? What if there is no '=' between a pair of ',' characters? What if a key trims to the empty string?